# Response time for nginx different for Longest transaction and Shortest transaction

Tags: debian, nginx

I run test for this nginx conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    #error_log  /var/log/debug.log  debug;

    server_name test1.ostrovok.ru;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:12345;
        client_max_body_size 20000k;
        charset  utf8;
    }

    location /photos {
        proxy_pass http://imageserver;
        proxy_store /srv/trololo/$request_uri;
        proxy_store_access   user:rw  group:rw  all:r;
        proxy_temp_path /srv/trololo/temp;
        access_log off;
    }
}

# Backend image server
server {

    listen       12346;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root /srv/trololo;
        sendfile off;
        aio on;
        output_buffers 200 10000k;
        gzip  off;
        directio 512;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
}

# Upstream
upstream imageserver {
    server localhost:12346;
}
```

Test:

```
siege -c 100 -r 5 -f urls.txt -t 120s --internet
```

Result

```
Transactions:              12352 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             120.00 secs
Data transferred:        1591.91 MB
Response time:              0.46 secs
Transaction rate:         102.93 trans/sec
Throughput:            13.27 MB/sec
Concurrency:               47.13
Successful transactions:       12352
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:           15.08
Shortest transaction:           0.05
```

Why such the difference between Longest transaction and Shortest transaction ?

The first 7 seconds of the test - good:

```
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  113575 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/900/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   16135 bytes ==> /photos/resize/900/100/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  132249 bytes ==> /photos/resize/500/700/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:    8513 bytes ==> /photos/resize/100/300/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:    8513 bytes ==> /photos/resize/100/600/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  113575 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/900/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   75669 bytes ==> /photos/resize/500/900/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  113575 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/1100/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   29708 bytes ==> /photos/resize/300/500/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  161191 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/300/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  200775 bytes ==> /photos/resize/800/700/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   29708 bytes ==> /photos/resize/300/200/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   29708 bytes ==> /photos/resize/300/1000/20110901/0300/22.png
```

But after:

```
HTTP/1.1 200   5.06 secs:   52441 bytes ==> /photos/resize/400/1100/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.06 secs:  235335 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/900/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.07 secs:  305657 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1000/500/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.07 secs:  252759 bytes ==> /photos/resize/900/1000/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.07 secs:  200775 bytes ==> /photos/resize/800/700/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.06 secs:   77258 bytes ==> /photos/resize/400/800/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  376880 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/700/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   16135 bytes ==> /photos/resize/900/100/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  161191 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/800/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   16135 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/100/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.06 secs:   44446 bytes ==> /photos/resize/400/200/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  343273 bytes ==> /photos/resize/900/800/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  518488 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/800/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  251162 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/300/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  161191 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/900/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   16135 bytes ==> /photos/resize/300/100/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:    8513 bytes ==> /photos/resize/100/600/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:    3242 bytes ==> /photos/resize/100/300/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   29708 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/100/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   24521 bytes ==> /photos/resize/200/1000/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   29708 bytes ==> /photos/resize/300/900/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  166648 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/400/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   52441 bytes ==> /photos/resize/400/500/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  113652 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1000/400/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  233737 bytes ==> /photos/resize/800/600/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  113575 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/500/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   53067 bytes ==> /photos/resize/300/1100/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   12417 bytes ==> /photos/resize/200/1100/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   99703 bytes ==> /photos/resize/800/300/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  252759 bytes ==> /photos/resize/900/700/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:    8513 bytes ==> /photos/resize/100/1000/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:    3242 bytes ==> /photos/resize/100/1000/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   52441 bytes ==> /photos/resize/400/1100/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:   99703 bytes ==> /photos/resize/800/300/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  376880 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/500/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  161191 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/1100/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   24521 bytes ==> /photos/resize/200/1000/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  251162 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/300/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  305657 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1000/500/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  518488 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/900/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.08 secs:  113575 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/1000/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   5.06 secs:  166648 bytes ==> /photos/resize/600/700/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.06 secs:  235335 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/800/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:  235335 bytes ==> /photos/resize/700/700/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   12417 bytes ==> /photos/resize/200/700/20110901/0300/22.png
HTTP/1.1 200   0.05 secs:   16135 bytes ==> /photos/resize/1100/100/20110831/2048/Ekafisha-Firefox.png
```

[Full Test Log file[1](http://narod.ru/disk/23634955001/test_log.txt.html)

And so on

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a purpose of proxying static requests to /photos to the same nginx on the same localhost? If you absolutely need it it's a good idea not to store content to a disk while proxying, your proxy should be set to a fully transparent mode (you should set `proxy_buffering` to `off`). Otherwise there is a useless disk activity in your setup - nginx creates temporary files at a proxying end for your /photos location. This can be a root cause of performance degradation for certain requests.